# Efficient function to return varying length vector from lookup table

Tags: r, vectorization, lookup-tables

I have three data sources:

```
types<-c(1,3,3)
places<-list(c(1,2,3),1,c(2,3))
lookup.counts<-as.data.frame(matrix(runif(9,min=0,max=10),nrow=3,ncol=3))
assigned.places<-rep.int(0,length(types))
```

the numbers in the "types" vector tell me what 'type' a given observation is. The vectors in the places list tell me which places the observation can be found in (some observations are found in only one place, others in all places). By definition there is one entry in types and one list in places for each observation. Lookup.counts tells me how many observations of each type are located in each place (generated from another data source).

I want to randomly assign each observation to a place based on a probability generated from lookup.counts. Using for loops it looks something like"

```
for (i in 1:length(types)){
  row<-types[i]
  columns<-places[[i]]
  this.obs<-lookup.counts[row,columns] #the counts of this type in each place
  total<-sum(this.obs)
  this.obs<-this.obs/total #the share of observations of this type in these places
  pick<-runif(1,min=0,max=1)

  #the following should really be a 'while' loop, but regardless it needs help
  for(j in 1:length(this.obs[])){
    if(this.obs[j] > pick){
      #pick is less than this county so assign
      pick<- 100 #just a way of making sure an observation doesn't get assigned twice
      assigned.places[i]<-colnames(lookup.counts)[j]
    }else{
      #pick is greater, move to the next category
      pick<- pick-this.obs[j]
    }
  }
}
```

I have been trying to vectorize this somehow, but am getting hung up on the variable length of 'places' and of 'this.obs'

In practice, of course, the lookup.counts table is quite a bit bigger (500 x 40) and I have some 900K observations with places lists of length 1 through length 39.

Comment: a good first step would be to put all this data in one object.  I think you can use a data.frame with an entry for each observation. But it is hard to tell from your description.  You could also use a nested named list but then you're going to `lapply` and that isnt "vectorized".

Comment: @Justin, `data.frame` won't accept columns of list type, nor rows with different numbers of columns.

Comment: @MvG yeah, but i would propose making multiple rows for the lists (e.g. long vs. wide data)

Comment: @Justin, multiple input rows per desired output result would mean `tapply` or similar, which doesn't feel that much better than `lapply`.

Comment: enter `data.table`. but I didn't think it through very far, hence my lack of an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work as well:

```
# More convenient if lookup.counts is a matrix.
lookup.counts<-matrix(runif(9,min=0,max=10),nrow=3,ncol=3)
colnames(lookup.counts)<-paste0('V',1:ncol(lookup.counts))

# A function that does what the for loop does for each i
test<-function(i) {
  this.places<-colnames(lookup.counts)[places[[i]]]
  this.obs<-lookup.counts[types[i],this.places]
  sample(this.places,size=1,prob=this.obs)
}

# Applies the function for all i
sapply(1:length(types),test)
```

Comment: Takes my function from hours to seconds. I knew there was a way. Wouldn't have gotten here on my own, and not sure why it is so much faster than MvG's but it is. Thanks.

Comment: If you are interested in learning how to do this yourself, I recommend trying to first make your for loop into a function. Try working with your original function, and just removing the `for` line and replacing it with `test<-function(i)`. Start from there, and see if you can then `sapply` your function. Then work on improving the function.

Answer (score 2):

To vectorize the inner loop, you can use `sample` or `sample.int` to choose from several alternaives with prescribed probabilities. Unless I read your code incorrectly, you want something like this:

```
assigned.places[i] <- sample(colnames(this.obs), 1, prob = this.obs)
```

I'm a bit surprised that you're using `colnames(lookup.counts)` instead. Shouldn't this be subset by `columns` as well? It seems that either I missed something, or there is a bug in your code.

the different lengths of your lists are a severe obstacle to vectorizing your outer loops. Perhaps you could use the `Matrix` package to store that information as sparse matrices. Then you could simply multiply probabilities by that vector to exclude those columns which are not in the places list of a given observation. But as you'd probably still use `apply` for the above sampling code, you might as well keep the list and use some form of `apply` to iterate over that.

The overall result might look somewhat like this:

```
assigned.places <- colnames(lookup.counts)[
  apply(cbind(types, places), 1, function(x) {
    sample(x[[2]], 1, prob=lookup.counts[x[[1]],x[[2]]])
  })
]
```

The use of `cbind` and `apply` isn't particularly beautiful, but seems to work. Each `x` is a list of two items, `x[[1]]` being the type and `x[[2]]` being the corresponding places. We use these to index `lookup.counts` just as you did. Then we use the found counts as relative probabilities when choosing the index of one of the columns we used in the subscript. Only after all these numbers have been assembled into a single vector by `apply` will the indices be turned into names based on `colnames`.

You can check whether things are faster if you don't `cbind`stuff together, but instead iterate over the indices only:

```
assigned.places <- colnames(lookup.counts)[
  sapply(1:length(types), function(i) {
    sample(places[[i]], 1, prob=lookup.counts[types[i],places[[i]]])
  })
]
```

Comment: These both work. Thanks, and thanks for the description of why they work. Very helpful. nograpes' answer is much faster so I am going with that, but your efforts are appreciated.

Comment: @csfowler, you may express your appreciation by pressing that beautiful upward-pointing arrow next to my question. :-) Although you can only accept a single answer, you may well upvote multiple correct and/or useful answers.